# How to listen for nested child updates in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Assuming I have database of a list of games, under each game I have a list of players, each player is an object.
Something like this: Games/Game#/Players/Player#.
I need the client to listen for updates for new game added (or specific field in a game), once a new game was added - listen for new players added to a game, or a specific field update in the player object.

Without listening for updates with a database ref for each game (there can 100's of games). The client doesn't know in advance which games/players are there. Thanks.

Example:

```
{
  "Games" : {
    "Game1" : {
      "Players" : {
        "Player1" : {
          "country" : "Ukraine",
          "points" : 90,
          "playerId" : 466356342
        },
        "Player2" : {
          "country" : "France",
          "points" : 2,
          "playerId" : 486370421
        },
        "Player3" : {
          "country" : "Russia",
          "points" : 34,
          "playerId" : 742659536
        }
      },
      "gameId" : 7220219,
      "gameName" : "ohio 5"
    },

    "Game2" : {
        "Players" : {
            "Player1" : {
              "country" : "Ukraine",
              "points" : 115,
              "playerId" : 466356342
            },
            "Player2" : {
              "country" : "Germany",
              "points" : 144,
              "playerId" : 486370421
            }

      },
      "gameId" : 8877942,
      "gameName" : "montana 6"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there an issue listening for child changed events on the games node?That will send an event of all of the cases listed in the question.

Comment: If I listen on the games node and do a change on Games/Game123/Players/Player1, the key that was changed on the callback is "Games/Game123", I dont know which player changed.
Code:
 var GamesRef = firebase.database().ref('/CashGames');

 GamesRef.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
  console.log("Update key = " + snapshot.key);
 });

Comment: Ah... So another option would be to add .childAdded, .childChanged and .childRemoved events to each Players node. That would send events when players are added, scores changed or players removed. A couple hundred observers shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.
I found this post which gives an excellent recursive example for achieving this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161161/how-to-tell-which-descendants-are-changed-with-onchild-changed